# .htaccess exclude directories from a https: rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my root directory where my main website is contained. On this site every request coming in I want to make sure it is over https: I use the following mod rewrite for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.treacyshotelwaterford.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My problem is that I have two sub directories which I run two other wordpress websites with different domains. Now since I introduced the mod rewrite in the .htaccess in the root all requests to the other domains get redirected to the main website. I have tried to exclude the folders but this has not effect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(spiritbeautyspa.ie|spiritleisurecentre.ie) https://www.treacyshotelwaterford.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I suppose those different domains are only _pointing_ to those sub-directories, but do _not_ have those in the actual URL path? Then of course you can not check for them with a `RewriteRule` – use a `RewriteCond` that checks the host name of the request instead.

Comment: If you would like to add this suggestion as an answer I can mark as being the solution. I added the condition RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.treacyshotelwaterford\.com [NC] and it now works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose those different domains are only *pointing* to those sub-directories, but do *not* have those in the actual URL path?

Then you can not check for them with a `RewriteRule` (because RewriteRule looks at the *path* component of the request URL only) – use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) that checks the host name of the request instead.